# UWP: PointerMoved if Pointer is being pressed

Tags: c#, uwp

I am currently trying to transport my WPF Control to UWP and am stuck at the PointerMoved event. While I was able to check the state of a Mousebutton in WPF and execute my code only if the state was true, I can't figure out the equivalent in UWP.

What I have in WPF

```
private void MyControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    { 
       //...
    }
}
```

What I want in UWP

```
private void MyControl_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if("PointerIsBeingPressed")
     {
         //...
     }
}
```

Every answer or hint to do things differently is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_PointerPressed

Comment: More info about pointer handling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/handle-pointer-input

Comment: @Chrille hint worked immediately, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft provides an example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_PointerPressed):

```
private void Target_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;

    if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {      
        Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(Target);
        if (ptrPt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
            //Handle button press
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i used from your documentation before and it worked, thanks!